# How do I access a child named with a random id in firebase?

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to be able to automatically access every child named with random ID keys nested inside "posts", is there a way to get the children of every child inside them?

[image]

I am completely new to firebase and managing database in general (started learning code 3 months ago), so I might have missed it in the documentation out of confusion rather than just dismissing it

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the actual random object key ID? Or just the properties for each object (typically, the properties are what you need, not the object ID)!

```
const arrayOfObjects = test2-2271b.posts[0];

arrayOfObjects.map(function(elem){
  console.log(elem.caption) // returns the caption value for each object
  console.log(elem.profilePic)
  console.log(elem.username)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `push()` method in firebase it will automatic generate unique key for your record.

The unique key is based on a timestamp, so list items will automatically be ordered chronologically. Because Firebase generates a unique key for each blog post, no write conflicts will occur if multiple users add a post at the same time.

use `set()` or `update()` method to create your own custom keys.

*below is sample code to get key of your 1st record*

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("posts/j5fp0kl*********");
ref.on('value', function(snapshot){
    var dataList = snapshot.val();
    var key = Object.keys(dataList)[0]; //this will return 1st key.         
    var keys = Object.keys(dataList);   //this will return all keys.
});
```